# Display sensor data in charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, bluetooth

I'm writing an app for my phone which gets sensor data (from a pressure sensor) in an ongoing data stream via Bluetooth. Data Storage and everything works fine so far.

Now I want to display this data in a chart, not in a static chart, but a live chart (for an example, click [here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/real-time-data/)).

Until now I used the [iOS Charts API](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/), but with this Framework I was only able to display the data in a static way until the moment I opened the ChartView.

Does anyone of you have an idea how I could realize my project?

Answer (score 0):

Chart gets redrawn (with animation) when you set a data to it. By data I mean any *ChartData* subclass.
I ended up storing dataSet in a property (was trying to update the values without re-setting the data):

```
chartDataSet.values = detectedNotes.enumerated().map { (index, element) in 
    return ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(index), y: Double(element.index)) }
chart.data = LineChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
```

I tried it with many entries (over 1k) and everything was fine.